# OpenOffice table formatting java

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I have created a table using Open Office API in Java. Now I want to format the table cell content like giving it background color, changing font, size, alignment.
My code is

```
XMultiServiceFactory xMSF = ( XMultiServiceFactory ) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XMultiServiceFactory.class, xdocument);

       // Creating a table with 13 rows and 2 columns
       XTextTable xTextTable = ( XTextTable ) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextTable.class, xMSF.createInstance( "com.sun.star.text.TextTable" ) );
       xTextTable.initialize( 2, 2); // rows, cols
       
       // insert table  in the xText
       
       xText.insertTextContent(xText.getEnd(), xTextTable, false);
       XPropertySet xPS1 = ( XPropertySet ) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
       XPropertySet.class, xTextTable );
 
       // Get table Width and TableColumnRelativeSum properties values
       int iWidth = ( Integer ) xPS1.getPropertyValue( "Width" );
       short sTableColumnRelativeSum = ( Short ) xPS1.getPropertyValue( "TableColumnRelativeSum" );
 
       // Calculate conversion ration
        double dRatio = ( double ) sTableColumnRelativeSum / ( double ) iWidth;
 
        // Convert our 20 mm (2000) to unknown ( relative ) units
       double dRelativeWidth = ( double ) 25000 * dRatio;
 
       // Get table column separators
       Object xObj = xPS1.getPropertyValue( "TableColumnSeparators" );
 
       TableColumnSeparator[] xSeparators = ( TableColumnSeparator[] )UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
       TableColumnSeparator[].class, xObj );
 
       // Last table column separator position
       double dPosition = sTableColumnRelativeSum - dRelativeWidth;
 
       // Set set new position for all column separators        
       for ( int i = xSeparators.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
       {
       xSeparators[i].Position = (short) Math.ceil( dPosition );
        dPosition -= dRelativeWidth;
       }
 
       // Do not forget to set TableColumnSeparators back! Otherwise, it doesn't work.
       xPS1.setPropertyValue( "TableColumnSeparators", xSeparators );

       
       XCellRange xCellRangeHeader = (XCellRange) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCellRange.class, xTextTable);
       XCell xCellHeader = null;
       XText xHeaderText = null;
       
      
       
       xCellHeader = xCellRangeHeader.getCellByPosition(0,0); // cols, rows
       xHeaderText = (XText) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XText.class, xCellHeader);
       xHeaderText.setString("Records Center Total Capacity");
       
       xCellHeader = xCellRangeHeader.getCellByPosition(1,0); // cols, rows
       xHeaderText = (XText) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XText.class, xCellHeader);
       xHeaderText.setString(""+RecordCentrecapacity);
       
       xCellHeader = xCellRangeHeader.getCellByPosition(0,1); // cols, rows
       xHeaderText = (XText) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XText.class, xCellHeader);
       xHeaderText.setString("Current Inventory For Week Ending");
       
       xCellHeader = xCellRangeHeader.getCellByPosition(1,1); // cols, rows
       xHeaderText = (XText) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XText.class, xCellHeader);
       xHeaderText.setString(""+currentTotalInventory);
```

Can you help me as i am new in this topic and i want to format the table according to my need.

Answer (score 0):

From the SWriter example at https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#Java_examples:

```
//create instance of a text table
com.sun.star.text.XTextTable xTT = null;

// get the property set of the text table
com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xTTPS = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet.class, xTT);

// Change the BackColor
try {
    xTTPS.setPropertyValue("BackTransparent", Boolean.FALSE);
    xTTPS.setPropertyValue("BackColor",Integer.valueOf(13421823));
    xTTRowPS.setPropertyValue("BackTransparent", Boolean.FALSE);
    xTTRowPS.setPropertyValue("BackColor",Integer.valueOf(6710932));

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't change the color " + e);
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}

// get the property set of the cursor
com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xTCPS = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet.class,
                          xTCursor);

// Change the CharColor and add a Shadow
try {
    xTCPS.setPropertyValue("CharColor",Integer.valueOf(255));
    xTCPS.setPropertyValue("CharShadowed", Boolean.TRUE);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't change the color " + e);
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

And from https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Samples/Java/Writer/TextTable#Horizontal_alignmentL

```
XPropertySet xPS = ( XPropertySet ) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XPropertySet.class, xTextTable );

xPS.setPropertyValue( "HoriOrient", com.sun.star.text.HoriOrientation.NONE );

int iLeftMargin, iRightMargin; // I assume you know how do you want to align your table

xPS.setPropertyValue( "LeftMargin", iLeftMargin );
xPS.setPropertyValue( "RightMargin", iRightMargin );
```

See also the C++ example at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/Tables#Changing_Appearance.

**EDIT**:

Here is a Python example that sets color and vertical alignment of a single cell.  XrayTool shows that TextTable cells support [com.sun.star.text.CellProperties](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/CellProperties.html).

```py
cell = table.getCellByName("A1")
cell.BackColor = int("FF00FF", 16)
cell.setPropertyValue("VertOrient", 2)
```

Comment: this is for the whole table but how to add color or align the text of a single cell of table and not other cells